# Why is the UI made by Android Jetpack Compose loaded so slow?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I create an app with Code A made by Android Jetpack Compose, It shows a blank UI long time before main UI is displayed, you can see Image A

I learned some sample project, such as the official sample project [Crane](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Crane).

So I modify Code A as Code B based *Crane*, I hope Code B to display a Loading UI quickly before main UI is displayed, but I still find it shows a blank UI long time before main UI is displayed with Code B.

BTW, I find the sample project *Crane* also shows a blank UI long time before main UI is displayed, you can see Image B.

**A:** How can I show a Loding UI quickly before main UI is displayed?

**B:** I can't understand Code B fully, why does the Loding UI dismiss automatically? does it due to the API function `MutableTransitionState`?

**C:** In Code B, even if I set `val SplashWaitTime: Long = 10000000`, I find the Loding UI dismissed about 2 sencond later just like I set `val SplashWaitTime: Long = 2000`, why?

**Code A**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActivityMain : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SoundMeterTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {                   
                    NavGraph()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Image A**

[image]

**Code B**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ActivityMain : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SoundMeterTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    val transitionState = remember { MutableTransitionState(SplashState.Shown) }
                    LandingScreen(
                        onTimeout = { transitionState.targetState = SplashState.Completed }
                    )
                    NavGraph()
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}


private const val SplashWaitTime: Long = 2000
enum class SplashState { Shown, Completed }

@Composable
fun LandingScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onTimeout: () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {       
        val currentOnTimeout by rememberUpdatedState(onTimeout)

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            delay(SplashWaitTime)
            currentOnTimeout()
        }
       Text("Loading..")
    }
}
```

**Image B**

[image]

Comment: what is in NavGraph()? code B is wrong, please check how transitionState used in Crane example, how it converted to alpha value for landing and main screens.  https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Crane/app/src/main/java/androidx/compose/samples/crane/home/MainActivity.kt#L125

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should test for performance in release build mode with R8 enabled

```
   release {

       minifyEnabled true

   }
```

You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-should-you-always-test-compose-performance-in-release-4168dd0f2c71) or here in [official document](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance#config) about performance, and first load of Compose might be slow and it's advised to use baseline profiles

Use a baseline profile

> Compose is distributed as a library, instead of being part of the
> Android platform. This approach lets us update Compose frequently and
> support older Android versions. However, distributing Compose as a
> library imposes a cost. Android platform code is already compiled and
> installed on the device. Libraries, on the other hand, need to be
> loaded when the app launches, and interpreted just-in-time when the
> functionality is needed. This can slow the app on startup, and
> whenever it uses a library feature for the first time.
>
> You can improve performance by defining baseline profiles. These
> profiles define classes and methods needed on critical user journeys,
> and are distributed with your app's APK. During app installation, ART
> compiles that critical code ahead-of-time, so it's ready for use when
> the app launches.
>
> It's not always easy to define a good baseline profile, and because of
> this Compose ships with one by default. You might not have to do any
> work to see this benefit. However, if you choose to define your own
> profile, you might generate one that doesn't actually improve your
> app's performance. You should test the profile to verify that it's
> helping. A good way to do that is to write Macrobenchmark tests for
> your app, and check the test results as you write and revise your
> baseline profile. For an example of how to write Macrobenchmark tests
> for your Compose UI, see the Macrobenchmark Compose sample.

Comment: This, @HelloCW you should never evaluate performance of compose in debug build type

Comment: You should evaluate performance in debug mode if it is so slow that it makes development much much less fun and productivity. Android is already slow before the introduction of ultra slow Jetpack Compose

Comment: minifyEnabled true will confuse my code, I just want to enable optimization, I don't want to confuse the code, I want the error stack and the number of log lines to be consistent with debug mode. What should I do, please ?

Comment: By the way, I don't care about the size of the APK file, because my APK is also very small in the debug mode

Answer (score 3):

Compose is very slow on debug builds, enable optimization (`minifyEnabled true`) and test UI performance on release builds only.