# Chain animations in LaunchedEffect using compose causes dropped frames

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

When I recently practiced writing chain animations with compose, I found that if I started the animation in LaunchedEffect, it would be a bit stuck when it was executed for the first time. In fact, when I log down, I find that the value in animate will be executed less than the second time and after.
This will visually look like a frame drop.
How can I fix it?
Thanks for your help again!

````
fun Demo() {
    var isDraw by remember { mutableStateOf(MenuDraw.None) }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
    ) {
        for (i in 0..2) {
            AnimButton1(isDraw, i) {
                isDraw = when (isDraw) {
                    MenuDraw.None -> MenuDraw.Open
                    MenuDraw.Open -> MenuDraw.Close
                    MenuDraw.Close -> MenuDraw.Open
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AnimButton1(
    isDraw: MenuDraw,
    index: Int,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {

    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f + index * 100) }
    var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f + index * 150) }


    LaunchedEffect(isDraw) {

        if (isDraw.isNone()) {
            return@LaunchedEffect
        }

        launch {
            animate(
                initialValue =
                if (isDraw.isOpen()) 0f + index * 100 else 200f + index * 100,
                targetValue = if (isDraw.isOpen()) 200f + index * 100 else 0f + index * 100,
                animationSpec = springSpec(isDraw)
            ) { value: Float, _: Float ->
                offsetX = value
                L.e("ZZZ offsetX $offsetX")
            }
        }

        launch {
            animate(
                initialValue = if (isDraw.isOpen()) 0f + index * 150 else 200f + index * 150,
                targetValue = if (isDraw.isOpen()) 200f + index * 150 else 0f + index * 150,
                animationSpec = springSpec(isDraw)
            ) { value: Float, _: Float ->
                offsetY = value
            }
        }

        if (isDraw.isOpen()) {
            delay(200)
        }
    }

    ShowImage1(offsetX, offsetY, onClick)
}

@Composable
private fun ShowImage1(
    offsetX: Float,
    offsetY: Float,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_aaa),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .graphicsLayer(
                translationX = offsetX,
                translationY = offsetY
            )
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .clickableSingle(onClick = {
                onClick()
            })
    )
}```
````

Comment: If you meant slow during first time running and eventually getting smooth as you continue using it, I think it's pretty normal in `debug` mode, I haven't tested my app yet, but they say the frames will be smooth in `release` mode, as far as I understand, both `jetpack compose` and `flutter` has the same "frame issues" during development. Have a look at this post, maybe it would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73316817/why-is-the-ui-made-by-android-jetpack-compose-loaded-so-slow